# Does vega only support to create chart, not diagram?

Tags: d3.js, charts, data-visualization, diagram, vega

I found that most of the examples of vega are illustrating creating charts which are with the x-axis, y-axis, title, and legends. There is even `axis` and `scales` defined in the specs. My question is:

**Does *vega* support to create diagrams? such as UML editor?**

Answer (score 0):

In principle, I'd say yes - among the examples on the Vega website is a [tree layout](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/tree-layout/) and a [network layout](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/force-directed-layout/). You could very likely adapt this to represent UML.